# how to time restrict the user to input in textbox for only 2 minutes in C# form

Tags: c#

how to time restrict the user to input in text-box for only 2 minutes in C# form ????????
will we use local time or create our own time stop etc and how??

I am writing a typing speed test program and the formula for calculating Net speed and Gross speed require exact time..................like 2 minutes or 3 minutes or 4 minutes
I have tried Datetime to store only time and then compare it with a +2(2 minutes from present time) value but the loop never ends

```
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;          
        string format = "mm";           
        format = time.ToString(format);

       int form = (int.Parse(format) + 01);
        int a=-1;
        while(a!=form)
        {
            time = DateTime.Now; 
            a=int.Parse(time.ToString(format));
            Console.Write(a.ToString());
        }
        Console.Write(time.ToString(format));
```

Comment: Create a timer on the form load and disable the text box after the end of the two minutes.

Comment: Initialize and start the timer when the typing starts. And on its first interval event, set textbox enable false.

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer on the form load and disable the text box after the end of the two minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I remember there is a timer control in Toolbox. You can set the enabled(or isenable) property of the textbox to false when the timer reaches 2 min. Then the user can no longer input.

Continue to ask if you still can't make it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer on your page.

```
 private Timer aTimer;
```

when typing start

```
public void start()
{

 // Create a timer with a two minutes interval.
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(120000);
    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;


 }

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   aTimer.Enabled = false;
// do what you want .........
}
```